# Specific filetype files should end with new line

Tags: filetype, options

my work project requires a newline at the end of a file. If I add a new line and save, it gets automatically removed. I work in Golang but the same behavior is observed in Lua, Rust and probably others. Only `.txt` files don't seem to have this behavior.

From what I read Vim does this automatically, but this is not the case for me. Either the language formatters are doing this, or there is something that I am missing. I am using the neovims built in lsp and `null-ls`

I saw that opening buffers as binary can help, but I don't know what that means, I am using the `Nvim-tree` as my file manager/ file tree so I open my files through there.

[Here are my vim sets](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/.dotfiles/blob/master/nvim/.config/nvim/lua/nikola/options.lua)

Basically, for Go filetypes I'd like to leave a newline at the end of my files.

Comment: Vim tends to add newline at the end of the file when not present. If it removes it it is probably the result of a plugin. Did you try to reproduce the problem with the plugin deactivated?

Comment: After disabling my entire lsp it seems to keep the newline, will continue debugging

Comment: Not related to your question here, but `vim.cmd([[set formatoptions-=cro]]) -- TODO: this doesn't seem to work` doesn't work as `-=` will remove that exact string (`cro`), so with the (Vim) default of `tcq` that won't work as the exact string `cro` doesn't appear. You need to call `set formatoptions-=c`, `set formatoptions-=r`, etc.

Comment: Hi @Nikola-Milovic do you have still the problem? Did you find a solution? Can you help us reproducing the problem?

Comment: Encountered some issues while debugging that took up my last weekend so I'll try and see what the culprit is and update the post

Comment: After more debugging I am left even more puzzled. All the files show a newline in VSCode but dont show the newline in Vim nor Github. It seems that this isnt an issue, can I somehow tell nvim to show a newline at the end?

Comment: "newline" != "new line". Do you need a "newline" or a "new line"?

Comment: @romainl since I dont clearly understand your comment I'll clarify. I want a new line (empty blank line) at the end of my Go files. But after further investigation, it seems that VIM just doesnt show them but they in theory are there, the new lines I mean.

Comment: Again, "newline" != "new line". There are two schools of thought about the "newline" character: one treats it as a "line separator" and the other one treats it as a "line terminator". Most historically relevant tools, including Vim, tend to follow the latter interpretation while many "modern" tools tend to follow the former one. Therefore, it is important to be precise: do you want the last line of your file to end with a "newline" character or do you want an extra empty "new line" at the end of your file? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16224292/546861 for background.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that controls how Vim fix the last end of line `endofline` and `fixendofline`:

You can query them with:

```
set endofline?
set fixendofline?
```

More help with: `:h endofline`

You can open a file a file in binary mode with:

```
:e ++bin yourfilepath
```

Or when starting Vim

```
vim -b yourfilepath
```